# Super key (A.K.A. Windows Key) not working in i3wm (Fedora 26)

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, i3, tiling-wm, super-key

### The **Super Key** does not work with **i3wm** when I configure it as the **configured modifier** key.

The used configuration file is the one that is initially generated choosing the Super/Windows Key instead of Alt.

**xev** recognises the key presses of the Super Key well enough.

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x200001,
    root 0x289, subw 0x0, time 11708837, (38,142), root:(763,601),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x200001,
    root 0x289, subw 0x0, time 11714471, (38,142), root:(763,601),
    state 0x2000, keycode 133 (keysym 0xff7e, Mode_switch), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So the identifier of the Super Key is ***Mode_switch***.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557029/super-key-the-windows-key-not-working-in-i3wm-in-14-04-1-lts) which talks about a very similar problem. However, the answer did not work on my case.

Using **xmodmap** (I know I should be using **setxkbmap** instead, but I couldn't find the equivalent for these commands) I did:

```
xmodmap -e "clear mod4"
```

Which worked as expected. And then:

```
xmodmap -e "add Mod4 = Mode_switch"
```

Which returned the following **error**:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  11
```

### QUESTION

1. What is the **setxkbmap** equivalent answer to the question I linked?
2. How do I avoid the error **xmodmap** gave me?

An answer to any of these could help me get the Super Key working.